# How to retrieve affected rows' primary key in bulk updates?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a comparison table, `differences(source1_id, source2_id, value)`, that holds the difference between pairs of values from different sources, which are stored in the table `values(source_id, value)`, that table should be updated in real-time. Actually I am retrieving each value's row, updating it and then updating the comparison table when the value changes. But that is slow due the number of queries needed.

I think I could use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to do a bulk update of the `values` table, but I need to know which values where updated to be able to update the `differences` table.

Comment: You could use triggers to insert into the `values` table whenever the source tables are updated.

Comment: @Barmar so I would use a trigger to update the `differences` table when the `values` table changes? But now the huge number of queries will be in the trigger, because the difference table holds _all_ the combinations of two rows from `values` table.

Comment: I think I misunderstood which table you were updating and what you want to record. But the basic answer is that there's no automatic way to get a list of all the rows updated by a query. There's nothing analogous to `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for updates.

Comment: All you can get is `ROW_COUNT()`, which is the number of rows updated.